# Endpoint on Specific Page Slug

Tags: plugin-development, endpoints

I have created an endpoint inside of my plugin:

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'libstaff', EP_PAGES );
```

Now I would like to have the endpoint work for one page only based on its slug. In this case, I want it to work ONLY when the page with the slug 'staff-directory' is at the end of the URL.

Comment: I think you just want to add a rewrite rule here rather than an endpoint.